# How to insert logo in email in ror?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to attach logo at the end of the email while sending mail . Below is my mailer code
employee_mailer.erb -

```
def user_confirmation(emp,pwd)
    @password = pwd
    @employee = emp
    @emp = Employee.find_by(id: @employee.id)
    mail(to: @emp.email, subject: 'HRMS Password Detail')
```

user_confirmation.html.erb -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>

  <body>
     <h4>Confirmation Email</h4>
    <p>
     <td> Welcome in HRMS of <%= @emp.company.name %> !!
     This is to inform you that your default password is <b><%= @password %></b>
     You can change your password.</td>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How I can send image as well with the above code .

Comment: All you need to do is to specify an absolute url of logo to img tag in your email's html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `img` tag as we do in HTML:

```
<img src="/location/image" alt="logo">
```

OR Rails way using Rails helper:

```
<%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
```

as you are sending a `HTML` email.

You can also add it as an inline attachment if required:

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url -%>
```

And in your mailer action:

```
attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read('path/to/logo.png')
```

**On a Side Note:**

I am not sure why you are doing this:

```
@employee = emp
@emp = Employee.find_by(id: @employee.id)
```

When you already have the employee in `emp` variable directly assign it to `@emp` or directly use `@employee` in which you have assigned it.

Hope this helps.